# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference When geting Data from Sharedpreference

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

The problem is when im saving some data from retrofit response , in my tokenManager with shared preference . and when i get it in my retrofitbuilder i have error cause she is null ,but when i get it in another activity i get the result . this is code

This is how i save the token from response :

```
JWT parsedJWT = new JWT(response.body());

                                    String token = response.body().toString();
                                    tokenManager.saveToken(token);
```

``

this is my TokenManger :

```
 public void saveToken(String data){
    editor.putString("key", data).commit();
 //  editor.putString("REFRESH_TOKEN", token.getValue()).commit();
}

public void deleteToken(){
    editor.remove("key").commit();
    //editor.remove("REFRESH_TOKEN").commit();
}

public AccesToken getToken(){

    AccesToken token = new AccesToken();
    token.setKey(prefs.getString("key", null));
    //token.setRefreshToken(prefs.getString("REFRESH_TOKEN", null));
    return token;
}
```

``
this is the retrofitBuilder class where i have the error :

```
          OkHttpClient newClient = client.newBuilder().addInterceptor(new 
           Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

            Request request = chain.request();

            Request.Builder builder = request.newBuilder();

        //  if(tokenManager.getToken().getKey() != null){

            builder.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " +tokenManager.getToken().getKey());
          //  builder.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " +data1);
        //}
             //     builder.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ );
            request = builder.build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
```

``

When I test this in another activity i get my result and that s working fine but not in my retrofitbuilder classee:

``

```
     String display =tokenManager.getToken().getKey();

                                    Log.w(TAG, "onResponseDisplay: " +display);
```

``

Comment: Are you sure that you have initialized "tokenManager" in retrofitBuilder class?

Comment: @PinkRabbits  yes i already do it `     public static <T> T createServiceWithAuth(Class<T> service, final TokenManager tokenManager){ `

Comment: can you post your error code?

Comment: @PinkRabbits `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.example.dell.pfeesen.Models.AccesToken com.example.dell.pfeesen.TokenManager.getToken()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dell.pfeesen.Network.RetrofitBuilder$2.intercept(RetrofitBuilder.java:81)` this the error

Comment: I guess your tokenManager is null in retrofitBuilder class. Can you try to get data with SharedPrefrence instance instead tokenManager in retrofitBuilder class. So we can understand where error comes from.

Comment: @PinkRabbits i already tryed but cant getsharedpreference in this class : this is my code to get Data in retrofitbuilder class : `  SharedPreferences pref=RetrofitBuilder.this.getSharedPreferences("try",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String tokeen=pref.getString("try","");` the getSharedPreferences with REd Color and ask me to create a method getSharedPreference in this class

Comment: You have to use context/activity to use sharedpreferences at out of an activity class. You can pass context in constructor as a parameter or just use "getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences...". This is not a good approach but just for see where the error comes from.

Comment: @PinkRabbits i already dot what u saying but when i wana pass value to the class . i cant , he told me to change  `public static <T> T createServiceWithAuth(Class<T> service, final TokenManager tokenManager){` to not static  .